# Manually trigger DataGridView event c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a winforms app and a DataGridView control for which I would like to manually trigger the `DataBindingComplete` event so that the function below will be run.

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            DoStuff();....
        }
```

How can I also force the manual firing of the event apart from the DataGridView automatically firing it?

Comment: Instead of calling the event, why not just call the DoStuff() method?  Same result.

Comment: I want the DoStuff() to be called only when the DataBindingComplete event fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call :

```
dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(dataGridView1, new DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs(ListChangedType.ItemAdded));
```

or replace ItemAdded by anything using intellisense.

Comment: That is not the problem. I want to manually fire the event. The function is ok.